# Selection on an object in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object like this in my vue data

```
data(){
   return  {
      selectedRecipe:'',
      recipe: [{
                    id:1,
                    name: 'Tuscan sun',
                    duration: '10'
                        },
                    {   id:2,
                        name: 'Montreal summer',
                        duration: '32'
                    },
                    {   id:3,
                        name: 'French spring',
                        duration: '24'
                    }
                ]
}
```

I have display the name of recipe on my select menu but
I need on summary page, display the duration of the recipe.

When I put item-value="duration",it put me the name on select menu and duration on the summary.

```
<v-select
    v-model="selectedRecipe"
    :items="recipe"
    item-text="name
    item-value="duration"

></v-select>
```

Summary page

```
<p class="answer">Recipe applied to the group :</p>
<p class="subtitle">{{selectedRecipe}}</p>
```

Comment: So, what is the question? It seems you got what you wanted.

Comment: No because I want to display duration and name in summary , now I just have one of them

Comment: `item-value="id".` (just guessing, I don't really use vue's build-in(?) components, so I have no idea what's v-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [return-object](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#customized-item-text-and-value) prop which will return the entire object of the selected item on selection.
So, add this in `v-select` tag:

```
<v-select 
    v-model="selectedRecipe" 
    :items="recipe" 
    item-text="name" 
    item-value="duration" 
    label="Select" 
    return-object>
```

And to print the values, you can do something like this:

```
<p class="answer">Recipe applied to the group : {{selectedRecipe.name}}</p>
<p class="subtitle">Duration: {{selectedRecipe.duration}}</p>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/r6whnbpf/12/) for demo.

Comment: Happy to help :)